# sharpdevelop .exe not working

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I'm a kind of newbie in c sharp , so i need some help on a issue i stumbled upon.I have written a small program which keeps my OfficeComunicator on status "available" when i lock the workstatiion ( instead of switching to status "away").Now i am using SharpDevelop tool and as soon as i compile the program and the exe comes up , its working beautifully.When i close the tool and just try to run the same .exe  from teh /bin/Debug directory its not working , which puzzles me , any suggestions where the issue could be ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Chances are the problem is in your code which you didn't show so we could only be guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Are using .NET or Mono as your run time?

If you use Mono you would need to make a Batch file to run the program.